# Multicore hacker tools?

Tags: password-cracking, tools, hashcat

Have a school project coming up in multicore programming. I'm interested in/have used hacking tools alot before, and was wondering if there were any good tools out there that could benefit from being implemented in OpenMP or some other parallel framework to speed them up. I was originally thinking password cracking but saw John the Ripper, etc all usually have multicore implementations. Any ideas? Honestly anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Most tools used by hackers do not benefit from multithreading because they are not computationally intensive. The ones that do, in particular ones related to credential cracking, are often written with multithreading or even GPGPU acceleration in mind in the first place. So I don't think you'll find all that many tools that *are* written like that, since only a small portion would actually benefit from it.

One hash cracking tool that is *not* multithreaded that may benefit from it would be aircrack-ng.